# Why doesn't a local variable live long enough for thread::scoped?

Tags: multithreading, rust, lifetime

Why doesn't Example 1 compile given that Example 2 compiles just fine? The only difference between the examples is that in Example 1 `value` is a function local variable, and in Example 2 `value` is an argument to the function.

**Example 1**

```
#![feature(scoped)]

use std::thread;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};

pub fn foo<F>() {
    let mut join_guards = Vec::new();
    let value = AtomicUsize::new(0);

    for _ in 0..10 {
        join_guards.push(thread::scoped(|| {
            value.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
        }));
    }
}
```

**Example 2**

```
#![feature(scoped)]

use std::thread;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};

pub fn foo<F>(value: AtomicUsize) {
    let mut join_guards = Vec::new();

    for _ in 0..10 {
        join_guards.push(thread::scoped(|| {
            value.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
        }));
    }
}
```

These are the error messages I get trying to compile Example 1:

```
error: `value` does not live long enough
         join_guards.push(thread::scoped(|| {
             value.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
         }));
note: reference must be valid for the block at 6:20...
pub fn foo<F>() {
    let mut join_guards = Vec::new();
    let value = AtomicUsize::new(0);

     for _ in 0..10 {
         join_guards.push(thread::scoped(|| {

note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 1 at 8:40
    let value = AtomicUsize::new(0);

     for _ in 0..10 {
         join_guards.push(thread::scoped(|| {
             value.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
         }));
```

Comment: Note that `thread::scoped` was removed from the standard library because it was not memory-safe. It has been [safely replaced by crates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32751956/155423).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`join_guards` is a vector of scoped threads with a certain shared lifetime. That lifetime is determined by which variables it closes over: `value` is the only one. Therefore, the lifetime of the scoped threads is the scope of `value`. Where is `value` legal? *After it is defined* and until it goes out of scope—that is, “the block suffix following statement 1 at 8:40”. `join_guards` must have as its lifetime a lifetime no greater than this, but if `join_guards` is defined *before* `value`, this is not the case.

The solution is to reverse the order of declaration:

```rust
let value = AtomicUsize::new(0);
let mut join_guards = Vec::new();
```

This explains why the second example works, also.