# How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?

Tags: multithreading, rust, reference, lifetime

I'm writing a WebSocket server where a web client connects to play chess against a multithreaded computer AI. The WebSocket server wants to pass a `Logger` object into the AI code. The `Logger` object is going to pipe down log lines from the AI to the web client. The `Logger` must contain a reference to the client connection.

I'm confused about how lifetimes interact with threads. I've reproduced the problem with a `Wrapper` struct parameterized by a type. The `run_thread` function tries to unwrap the value and log it.

```rs
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::thread;

struct Wrapper<T: Debug> {
    val: T,
}

fn run_thread<T: Debug>(wrapper: Wrapper<T>) {
    let thr = thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("{:?}", wrapper.val);
    });

    thr.join();
}

fn main() {
    run_thread(Wrapper::<i32> { val: -1 });
}
```

The `wrapper` argument lives on the stack, and its lifetime doesn't extend past `run_thread`'s stack frame, even though the thread will be joined before the stack frame ends. I'd could copy the value off the stack:

```rs
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::thread;

struct Wrapper<T: Debug + Send> {
    val: T,
}

fn run_thread<T: Debug + Send + 'static>(wrapper: Wrapper<T>) {
    let thr = thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("{:?}", wrapper.val);
    });

    thr.join();
}

fn main() {
    run_thread(Wrapper::<i32> { val: -1 });
}
```

This will not work if `T` is a reference to a big object I don't want copied:

```rs
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::thread;

struct Wrapper<T: Debug + Send> {
    val: T,
}

fn run_thread<T: Debug + Send + 'static>(wrapper: Wrapper<T>) {
    let thr = thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("{:?}", wrapper.val);
    });

    thr.join();
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..1000 {
        v.push(i);
    }

    run_thread(Wrapper { val: &v });
}
```

Which results in:

```
error: `v` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:22:32
   |
22 |     run_thread(Wrapper { val: &v });
   |                                ^ does not live long enough
23 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

The only solution I can think of is to use an `Arc`.

```
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;

struct Wrapper<T: Debug + Send + Sync + 'static> {
    arc_val: Arc<T>,
}

fn run_thread<T: Debug + Send + Sync + 'static>(wrapper: &Wrapper<T>) {
    let arc_val = wrapper.arc_val.clone();
    let thr = thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("{:?}", *arc_val);
    });

    thr.join();
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..1000 {
        v.push(i);
    }

    let w = Wrapper { arc_val: Arc::new(v) };
    run_thread(&w);

    println!("{}", (*w.arc_val)[0]);
}
```

In my real program, it appears that both the `Logger` and the connection object must be placed in `Arc` wrappers. It seems annoying that the client is required to box the connection in an `Arc` when it is internal to the library that the code is parallelized. This is especially annoying because the lifetime of the connection is guaranteed to be greater than the lifetime of the worker threads.

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 78):

The basic thread support in the standard library allows the created threads to outlive the thread that created them; that's a good thing! However, if you were to pass a reference to a stack-allocated variable to one of these threads, there's no guarantee that the variable will still be valid by the time the thread executes. In other languages, this would allow the thread to access invalid memory, creating a pile of memory safety issues.

One solution is *scoped threads* — threads that are guaranteed to exit before the parent thread exits. These can ensure that stack variables in the parent thread will be available for the entire duration of the thread.

### Rust 1.63

[`std::thread::scope`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/thread/fn.scope.html) returns to stable Rust after a 7-year break ([removal](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/6399bb425b3a82111cd554737f194c95b8f6bad5), [return](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/93203)).

```rust
use std::{thread, time::Duration};

fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    thread::scope(|scope| {
        for e in &mut vec {
            scope.spawn(move || {
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
                *e += 1;
            });
        }
    });

    println!("{:?}", vec);
}
```

### Earlier Rust versions or when you need more control

#### crossbeam

We aren't limited to the standard library; a popular crate for scoped threads is [crossbeam](https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam):

```
use crossbeam; // 0.6.0
use std::{thread, time::Duration};

fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    crossbeam::scope(|scope| {
        for e in &mut vec {
            scope.spawn(move |_| {
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
                *e += 1;
            });
        }
    })
    .expect("A child thread panicked");

    println!("{:?}", vec);
}
```

#### rayon

There are also crates like [rayon](https://crates.io/crates/rayon) that abstract away the low-level details of "threads" but allow you to accomplish your goals:

```
use rayon::iter::{IntoParallelRefMutIterator, ParallelIterator}; // 1.0.3
use std::{thread, time::Duration};

fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    vec.par_iter_mut().for_each(|e| {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
        *e += 1;
    });

    println!("{:?}", vec);
}
```

### About the examples

Each example spawns a number of threads and mutates a local vector in place with no locking, no `Arc`, and no cloning. Note that the mutation has a `sleep` call to help verify that the calls are happening in parallel.

You can extend the examples to share a reference to any type which implements [`Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html), such as a `Mutex` or an `Atomic*`. Using these would introduce locking, however.

---

> the client is required to box the connection in an `Arc` when it is internal to the library that the code is parallelized

Perhaps you can hide your parallelism better then? Could you accept the logger and then wrap it in an `Arc` / `Mutex` before handing it off to your threads?

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply!

My solution was to make the `Logger` implement `Clone`, and have a field with type `Arc<Mutex<Connection>>`. Then the user could pass a clone of the logger to the threaded code.

The user can't transfer ownership of the `Connection` to the threaded code (the user needs it for other purposes), so I don't see that it is possible for the threaded code to conveniently do the `Arc` and boxing on behalf of the user.

Comment: What do you do if the variable you are trying to pass around can't implement Clone/Copy? like a USB device handle from the rusb crate

Comment: @BrandonRos `Vec` doesn't implement `Copy` and `Clone` isn't used in these code examples. The code presented here works fine for such types.