# Writing to a memory-mapped file from multiple threads in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, mmap, memory-mapped-files

What is the correct way to write to a memory mapped file with no synchronization from multiple threads in Rust?

I need to create a 40+ GB file using multiple threads. The file is used as a giant vector of u64 values. Threads do not need any kind of synchronization -- each thread's output will be unique to that thread, but each thread does NOT get its own slice. Rather, the nature of the data ensures each thread will generate a set of unique positions in the file to write to.  Simple example -- each thread writes to a position `[ind / thread_count]`, where `ind` goes to millions. For `thread_count = 2`, one thread writes to odd positions, and the other to even.

I have used [memmap2](https://docs.rs/memmap2/0.5.0/memmap2/) - a new maintained fork of the [memmap](https://docs.rs/memmap/0.7.0/memmap/) lib.  The `memmap2` seems to do everything I need for the access, but I do not know how to properly use it from multiple threads.

Comment: A lazy way would be for each thread to just create its own mapping of the region that it needs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass disjoint slices from a vector to different threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33818141/how-do-i-pass-disjoint-slices-from-a-vector-to-different-threads)

Comment: @kmdreko it doesn't seem so -- each thread will not write to a dedicated slice. Instead, each thread could randomly write pretty much anywhere in the giant file, but I just know that they won't conflict when writing (because of the nature of the data being processed)

Comment: @NateEldredge I was actually thinking if its ok for each thread to open its own mutable map of a file?  My only concern is that i would have to do my own thread management instead of using `rayon::iter::ParallelBridge`... I am new to Rust, so not sure how to even start with that.

Comment: I would seriously consider transmuting the `&[u8]` slice returned by `Mmap::as_ref()` to `&[AtomicU8]`. Such transmute is unsafe but sound because `AtomicU8` is guaranteed to have the same representation as `u8`. Share the resulting slice (and only that slice) among your threads, and have them store data using `slice[pos].store(value, Ordering::Relaxed)`, which will (on x86) be compiled into an ordinary store.

Comment: @user4815162342 could you provide a sample of how to do this? I'm a Rust newbie despite lots of other language experience, so would be very helpful to see a working example of that. Thx!

Comment: @YuriAstrakhan I meant [something like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ab57740082c9e1c6fc3ba64ffe5561bb). (Using `memmap` as example because the playground supports it, `memmap2` should work the same.)

Comment: @user4815162342 Transmuting `&[u8]` into `&[AtomicU8]` is not sound because `AtomicU8` has interior mutability but `u8` does not. Mutating data reached through a shared reference without interior mutability [is undefined behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html). To make it sound you would need to use `&mut [u8]` instead of `&[u8]` (which is only a [small change](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e9547ee6cc73cee6f05280c71abf252a) to your example).

Comment: @Frxstrem Makes sense, thanks. What do you think of using `from_raw_parts()` in preference to `transmute`?

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that your threads never write to same offsets, you can just map the file to the memory and write to it using `std::ptr::write`.

Example:

```rust
use std::fmt::Write;
use std::fs::File;

use memmap2::{MmapMut, MmapOptions};

fn main() {
    const CHUNK_SIZE: usize = 32;
    const TOTAL_SIZE: usize = 40 * usize::pow(2, 30);

    let file_name = {
        let mut p = std::env::temp_dir();
        p.push("many_gib_file.tmp");
        p
    };
    println!("Creating file {}", file_name.as_os_str().to_string_lossy());
    let file: File = File::options()
        .read(true)
        .write(true)
        .create(true)
        .open(&file_name)
        .expect("Failed to create file");
    file.set_len(TOTAL_SIZE.try_into().unwrap())
        .expect("Failed to resize file");

    let mut mmap: MmapMut = unsafe {
        MmapOptions::new()
            .offset(0)
            .len(TOTAL_SIZE)
            .map_mut(&file)
            .expect("Failed to map file")
    };

    let start_ptr = mmap.as_mut_ptr();

    #[derive(Copy, Clone)]
    struct ShareablePtr(*mut u8);

    // SAFETY: We never alias data when writing from multiple threads.
    // Writer threads finish before unmapping.
    unsafe impl Send for ShareablePtr {}

    let start_ptr = ShareablePtr(start_ptr);
    std::thread::scope(|s| {
        // Even thread
        s.spawn(move || {
            let start_ptr = start_ptr;
            let start_ptr: *mut u8 = start_ptr.0;

            let mut value = String::with_capacity(CHUNK_SIZE);
            let mut offset = 0;
            while offset + CHUNK_SIZE <= TOTAL_SIZE {
                value.clear();

                write!(&mut value, "Even:{:26}\n", offset).unwrap();
                assert_eq!(value.len(), CHUNK_SIZE);

                unsafe {
                    // SAFETY: We never overlap on writes.
                    // Pointer is living because we using scoped threads.
                    std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(
                        value.as_ptr(),
                        start_ptr.add(offset),
                        CHUNK_SIZE,
                    );
                }

                // Add offset for ourselves and for odd thread.
                offset += 2 * CHUNK_SIZE;
            }

            // Make writes visible for main thread
            // It is not necessary when using `std::thread::scope` but may be necessary in your case.
            std::sync::atomic::fence(std::sync::atomic::Ordering::Release);
        });
        // Odd thread
        s.spawn(move || {
            let start_ptr = start_ptr;
            let start_ptr: *mut u8 = start_ptr.0;

            let mut value = String::with_capacity(CHUNK_SIZE);
            // We want it to not overlap with even thread.
            let mut offset = CHUNK_SIZE;
            while offset + CHUNK_SIZE <= TOTAL_SIZE {
                value.clear();

                write!(&mut value, "Odd:{:27}\n", offset).unwrap();
                assert_eq!(value.len(), CHUNK_SIZE);

                unsafe {
                    // SAFETY: We never overlap on writes.
                    // Pointer is living because we using scoped threads.
                    std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(
                        value.as_ptr(),
                        start_ptr.add(offset),
                        CHUNK_SIZE,
                    );
                }

                // Add offset for ourselves and for even thread.
                offset += 2 * CHUNK_SIZE;
            }

            // Make writes visible for main thread
            // It is not necessary when using `std::thread::scope` but may be necessary in your case.
            std::sync::atomic::fence(std::sync::atomic::Ordering::Release);
        });
    });

    // Make writes visible for main thread
    // It is not necessary when using `std::thread::scope` but may be necessary in your case.
    std::sync::atomic::fence(std::sync::atomic::Ordering::Acquire);

    mmap.flush().expect("Failed to flush");
    drop(mmap);
    drop(file);

    println!("Finished!");
}
```

Note that you probably should flush writed chunks sometimes to avoid consuming too much RAM. I didn't wrote that logic because it adds complexity to my example.

If you truly never overlap your writes, they should be correctly written from CPU caches to RAM and from RAM to disk even without any additional synchronization from your part because it is a responsibility of CPU and operating system.