# Why do I need to implement `Copy` and `Clone` if I'm sharing an immutable reference with multiple threads?

Tags: multithreading, reference, rust

Still struggling with the Rust mind shift, now I have this use case - one configuration for a multi-threaded `TcpListener`:

```
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream, ToSocketAddrs};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    serve("127.0.0.1:3333", Configuration { do_something: true });
}

//#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Configuration {
    pub do_something: bool,
}

pub fn serve<A: ToSocketAddrs>(addr: A, conf: Configuration) {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(addr).expect("bind failed");

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Ok(stream) => {
                thread::spawn(move || {
                    handle_client(stream, &conf);
                });
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Connection failed: {}", e);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn handle_client(stream: TcpStream, conf: &Configuration) {
    if conf.do_something {
        //stream....
    }
}
```

I'm happy that the `TcpStream` is consumed by `handle_client`, that's it's purpose, but why does `Configuration` have to be copied for each thread? I'd like to have just one copy and share an immutable reference with all threads. Is that possible? Or perhaps I'm missing the point.

Why do I need the `Copy` and `Clone` traits if I'm passing `Configuration` by reference? This confused me a good deal:

```
error[E0382]: capture of moved value: `conf`
  --> src/main.rs:19:64
   |
19 |                 thread::spawn(move || { handle_client(stream, &conf); });
   |                               -------                          ^^^^ value captured here after move
   |                               |
   |                               value moved (into closure) here
   |
   = note: move occurs because `conf` has type `Configuration`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implementing `Copy` (`Clone` is incidental here) only fixes the problem because implementing it allows the compiler to implicitly duplicate the `Configuration` struct, passing a copied value into the thread.

It needs to pass the variable by value because you told the compiler to `move` all used values into the closure:

```
thread::spawn(move || {
//            ^^^^ HERE
    handle_client(stream, &conf);
});
```

The *entire purpose* of the `move` keyword is to tell the compiler "no, don't try to infer how variables are used inside this closure, just move everything in".

When you `move` `&conf`, the compiler says "OK, I'll move `conf` into the closure then take a reference to it".

In your case, you can just remove the `move` keyword:

```
thread::spawn(|| {
    handle_client(stream, &conf);
});
```

If you really need to be able to use the `move` keyword **and** pass in a reference, you need to *move in a reference*:

```
let conf = &conf;
thread::spawn(move || {
    handle_client(stream, conf);
});
```

This still doesn't allow your code to compile because there's no guarantee that the reference outlives the thread. That's discussed thoroughly in [Passing a reference to a stack variable to a scoped thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32750829/155423).

Comment: Thank you @Shepmaster, I gather that I cannot share a reference to conf with the thread because the thread may outlive the scope so again I would need a scoped thread for that. Correct? If I just remove the `move` I get the "may outlive borrowed value `conf`".

Comment: @RobertCutajar-Robajz yes; that would be why the final paragraph of my answer says *This still doesn't allow your code to compile because there's no guarantee that the reference outlives the thread* and then links to an answer that talks about scoped threads. Is there some other way I could have worded that to be more understandable?

Comment: Aha! :o) I thought you refered to the "move in a reference". Perhaps it would be clearer to say upfront that I cannot do this immutable reference sharing with thread::spawn at all without a copy. Thanks a lot for your effort to educate the seeker :o)