# Getting a read-only version of an Arc<RwLock<Foo>>?

Tags: rust, rwlock

I have an `Arc<RwLock<Foo>>`.

Is there a way to make something out of this, on which the `RwLock`'s write() does not exist?  i.e. Is there some form of `RLock` which I can make from an `RwLock`.

Use case:  I have a `Foo`.  More than one part of my code needs to mutate the Foo (hence the RwLock), but the majority of my code must only ever have read-only access to the Foo.

Is there a way of achieving this?  Or is there a way of doing this without `RwLock`?

Comment: similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68908091/how-do-i-send-read-only-data-to-other-threads-without-copying

Comment: just return the `LockGuard` (even the wrapped `Result`) from `read`

Comment: It's hard to answer without a concrete example, but you can try to not use `RwLock` and instead [`Arc::get_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.get_mut).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman unfortunately I have multiple clones of the `Arc<RwLock<Foo>>`, in different threads.

Comment: @Netwave Would this work if the "read only" reference needs to live for the life of the process?  Or would it block the writers?

Comment: @fadedbee, you need to release the lock at some point, you shouldnt have a reference to the ward (because it would be locked for the entire time, so you would not be able to write it), but you can have as much of those as you want for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write your own struct that *contains* the `Arc<RwLock<Foo>>`.

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct FooReadOnly(Arc<RwLock<Foo>>);

impl FooReadOnly {
    pub fn read(&self) -> LockResult<RwLockReadGuard<'_, Foo>> {
        self.0.read()
    }

}
```

(A fully fleshed-out version would also contain a wrapper for `try_read()`.)

The general pattern worth noting here is: instead of your data type being *visibly* inside an `Arc<RwLock<...>>`, your public type *contains* the `Arc`. This allows much more flexibility in what kind of “handles” you can offer than exposing the Arc. This is a fairly common pattern in Rust — if you've ever used a library type that notes you can clone it and get another handle to the same thing, there's a good chance it's doing the same thing inside (if it's not actually a handle to an OS resource like a file descriptor).

If you wanted to fully hide the implementation details, you would also wrap the `RwLockReadGuard` — all it needs to do is implement `Deref<Target = Foo>` and forward that to the guard. Such wrappers can also do things like `Deref`ing to some *part* of the `Foo` rather than an `&Foo` exactly.