# How to share a pointer to a mutable variable to a thread?

Tags: rust, thread-safety, uci

I have to implement the UCI [protocol](http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/UCIProtocol.html) for my chess engine.

It requires to read commands from command line. When the `go` command is sent, a search has to be started. However, during this search, other commands such as `stop` still have to be received. In the case of `stop`, the search has to quit altogether.

This is how the code looks (with leaving out non-important details).

```rust
pub fn main() {
    let mut stop: bool = false;
    loop {
        line.clear();
        stdin.read_line(&mut line).ok().unwrap();
        let arg: Vec<&str> = line.split_whitespace().collect();
        let cmd = arg[0];
        match cmd.trim() {
            "" => continue,
            "go" => {
                stop = false;
                thread::spawn(move || start_search(&stop, GameState, History, Timecontrol));
            }
            "stop" => {
                stop = true;
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(50));
            }
            "quit" => {
                stop = true;
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(50));
                break;
            }
            _ => {
                println!("Unknown command {}", line);
            }
        }
    }
}

pub fn start_search(stop_reference: &bool, _: GameState, _: History, _: Timecontrol) {
    /* Do search stuff here...
     */
    //Has to break when stop_reference is set to true
}
```

This code doesn't work because I assume the field just get's copied. However I have tried giving structs and then the code complains because you can't have a mutable reference and a normal reference both at once. I have also looked into ways to communicate with a thread. However most of the solutions used a channel to achieve that, but I think a channel doesn't work in my case since the thread is always calculating, so it would only receive the channels' command after it has terminated anyway.

Comment: You want to use AtomicBool. I advice you to read more about Rust before playing with threads.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios If I replace my bools with AtomicBool , I get the compile error:
`error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `stop`
  --> src\uci\uci_parser.rs:34:18
   |
34 |                 *stop.get_mut()=false;;
   |                  ^^^^ value borrowed here after move
...
42 |                 thread::spawn(move || {
   |                               ------- value moved into closure here, in pre
vious iteration of loop
   |
   = note: move occurs because `stop` has type `std::sync::atomic::AtomicBool`,
which does not implement the `Copy` trait`

Comment: You need a little more than an atomicBool. You need an Arc. Here's an example (without sleep): https://github.com/Canop/broot/blob/master/src/app.rs#L240 Do you want an answer for that?

Comment: You have to use `Arc` to obtain your goal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a special reference, an [Arc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) to share the boolean value between threads:

```
pub fn main() {
    let stop = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false));
    loop {
        //...

        let stop = Arc::clone(&stop);
        thread::spawn(move || {
            start_search(stop);
        })
    }
}
```

```
pub fn start_search(stop: Arc<AtomicBool>) {
    loop {
        if stop.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
            // STOP
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. However I had to move `Arc:.clone(&stop)` outside of the closure, else I got a compiler error

Comment: @Fabianv.d.W right. Edited.

Comment: Is there an issue to write: `stop.clone()`?

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios yes, see the doc of Arc: "The Arc::clone(&from) syntax is the most idiomatic because it conveys more explicitly the meaning of the code"

Comment: See also [How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32750829/155423); which allows you to avoid the `Arc` entirely.