# Why Mutex was designed to need an Arc in Rust

Tags: rust, mutex, smart-pointers, interior-mutability

Why was `Mutex<T>` designed to need an `Arc<T>` if the only reason to use a `Mutex<T>` is for concurrent code, i.e. multiple threads? Wouldn't it be better to alias a `Mutex<T>` to an atomic reference in the first place? I'm using https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-03-shared-state.html as reference.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't need an `Arc` to use a `Mutex`. The signature of `lock` (the most used method on a `Mutex`) is `pub fn lock(&self) -> LockResult<MutexGuard<T>>` which means you need a reference to the `Mutex`.

The problem arises with the borrow-checker. It is not able to prove certain guarantees when passing a reference to threads which might outlive the original `Mutex`. That's why you use `Arc` which guarantees that the value inside lives as long as the last `Arc` lives.

```
use lazy_static::lazy_static; // 1.3.0
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::thread::spawn;

lazy_static! {
    static ref M: Mutex<u32> = Mutex::new(5);
}

fn a(m: &Mutex<u32>) {
    println!("{}", m.lock().unwrap());
}

fn b(m: &Mutex<u32>) {
    println!("{}", m.lock().unwrap());
}

fn main() {
    let t1 = spawn(|| a(&M));
    let t2 = spawn(|| b(&M));

    t1.join().unwrap();
    t2.join().unwrap();
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2d0f7b2ddad249580aeb3d38fe42929b))

Comment: I think scoped threads are a more obvious use of a `Mutex` (or `RwLock` or `Atomic`) without reference counting: [How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32750829/155423).