# How can I avoid giving a static lifetime to something that already has an explicit lifetime?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, borrowing, lifetime-scoping

I'm building a Rust library that exposes the following simple flow to a C++ client application:

1. Client Application (CA) calls an API to create a FooClient, which amongst other things creates a tokio::Runtime.
2. CA calls FooClient.lookup("http://stackoverflow.com", callback) where callback is a Function Pointer.
3. FooClient takes the URI and copies it to a Context struct. The context struct has a reference to the FooClient's tokio::Runtime, amongst other things.  This context is passed through several functions of business logic.  The Context has an explicit lifetime of `'a`, so it is shorter than `'static`.
4. When the heavy processing is done, Rust calls the callback it was given (this was translated to a FnOnce and works fine)

During Step 3's business logic, it is often necessary to make a web request, which I'd like to schedule asynchrounously using the `&tokio::Runtime` stored in the Context.

Here is simplified code, which does not compile:

```
fn fork_task(context: &Context, uri: Uri, callback: FnOnce) {
   let handle = context.async_scheduler.handle().clone();
   let th = thread::spawn(move || {
       handle.block_on(async {
           call_service(context, uri);
       });
   });

   th.join().unwrap();
   callback();
}
```

The error this gives me is:

```
error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `context`
    |
335 |     context: &Context,
    |              -------- help: add explicit lifetime `'static` to the type of `context`: `&Context<'static>`
...
348 |     let th = thread::spawn(move || {
    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime `'static` required
```

It actually throws this error for every parameter used within the spawn, not just context.  However, I don't think `'static` is right here.  I think if anything, it should be '`a`, which is tied to the explicit lifetime of my Context.

Is there some form of workaround I can do?  Perhaps with `Arc<Mutex<Context>>`, although that doesn't seem like it would do what I want correctly either.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.3.0/crossbeam/struct.Scope.html#method.spawn

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750829/how-can-i-pass-a-reference-to-a-stack-variable-to-a-thread)