# How to race a collection of Futures in Rust?

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, rust, future

Given a collection of `Future`s, say a `Vec<impl Future<..>>`, how can I block and run all of the `Future`s concurrently until the first `Future` is ready?

The closest feature I can find is the [select macro](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/macro.select.html) (which is also [available in Tokio](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.13/tokio/macro.select.html)). Unfortunately it only works with an explicit number of `Future`s, instead of handling a collection of them.

There is an equivalent of this feature in Javascript, called [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race). Is there a way to do this in Rust?

Or perhaps there's a way to fulfill this use case using another pattern, perhaps with channels?

Comment: I can't write a proper answer right now, but check if the `FuturesUnordered` (https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/stream/struct.FuturesUnordered.html) is what you want.

Comment: I think you might want [`futures::future::select_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/fn.select_all.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I spawn asynchronous methods in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63434977/how-can-i-spawn-asynchronous-methods-in-a-loop) In particular, see the `join_parallel` function defined in the answer.

Comment: @user4815162342 I don't think that suggestion answers the question, because `join_parallel` requires waiting for *all* of the futures to finish executing. Instead, I only want to wait until the fastest future is finished, then unblock the thread. Also, executing the futures in parallel is not a requirement for this question. But thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured out a solution using the [`select_all` function from the `futures`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/fn.select_all.html) library.

Here is a simple example to demonstrate how it can be used to race a collection of futures:

```rust
use futures::future::select_all;
use futures::FutureExt;
use tokio::time::{delay_for, Duration};

async fn get_async_task(task_id: &str, seconds: u64) -> &'_ str {
    println!("starting {}", task_id);
    let duration = Duration::new(seconds, 0);

    delay_for(duration).await;

    println!("{} complete!", task_id);
    task_id
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let futures = vec![

        // `select_all` expects the Futures iterable to implement UnPin, so we use `boxed` here to
        // allocate on the heap:
        // https://users.rust-lang.org/t/the-trait-unpin-is-not-implemented-for-genfuture-error-when-using-join-all/23612/3
        // https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.boxed

        get_async_task("task 1", 5).boxed(),
        get_async_task("task 2", 4).boxed(),
        get_async_task("task 3", 1).boxed(),
        get_async_task("task 4", 2).boxed(),
        get_async_task("task 5", 3).boxed(),
    ];

    let (item_resolved, ready_future_index, _remaining_futures) =
        select_all(futures).await;

    assert_eq!("task 3", item_resolved);
    assert_eq!(2, ready_future_index);
}
```

Here's a link to the code above:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f32b2ed404624c1b0abe284914f8658d

Thanks to @Herohtar for suggesting `select_all` in the comments above!