# How to race collection of futures in Rust and with retry

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I have a collection of Futures, and I would like to execute all of them and get the first one that resolves successfully and abort the others still processing.

But I want to take care of the scenario where the first future that resolves actually returns an invalid value, hence leading to a situation where a retry is needed.

I found the [select!](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/macro.select.html) macro from tokio, but it does not supporting racing a collection of futures. With `select!` one needs to explicitly list the futures that would be raced...making it not usable for my usecase. Also i do not see it supporting any retry mechanism.

So how do I race collection of futures in Rust and with retry?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63715918/how-to-race-a-collection-of-futures-in-rust

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your futures return `Result` and you need to retry on `Err`, and by "retry" you don't mean to retry the failed future but to try others, you can use `futures`' [`select_ok()`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/fn.select_ok.html):

```rust
async fn first_successful<T, E: fmt::Debug, Fut>(futures: Vec<Fut>) -> T
where
    E: fmt::Debug,
    Fut: Future<Output = Result<T, E>> + Unpin,
{
    let (output, _remaining_futures) = futures::future::select_ok(futures)
        .await
        .expect("all futures failed");
    output
}
```

If not, and you need more control, you can use the powerful [`FuturesUnordered`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/struct.FuturesUnordered.html). For example, for trying others with a custom predicate:

```rust
use futures::stream::StreamExt;

async fn first_successful<Fut: Future + Unpin>(
    futures: Vec<Fut>,
    mut failed: impl FnMut(&Fut::Output) -> bool,
) -> Fut::Output {
    let mut futures = futures::stream::FuturesUnordered::from_iter(futures);
    while let Some(v) = futures.next().await {
        if !failed(&v) {
            return v;
        }
    }
    panic!("all futures failed");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just a quick clarification. In the example using FuturesUnordered, won't the operation be synchronous? I ask because I see a while loop...it looks lke the future will be tried one after the other...if so does that not defeat the puporse of using futures?

Comment: @FinlayWeber `FuturesUnordered` take care to poll all the futures.