# Lifetime problem when spawning a thread with arc mutex

Tags: rust, lifetime

I don't understand why the code below fails

```
use std::sync::{Arc};
use futures::lock::Mutex;

struct A<'a>{
    a: &'a u8
}

impl<'a> A<'a>{
    pub fn run(a: Arc<Mutex<Self>>) {
        let stack_thread = std::thread::Builder::new()
            .spawn(move || {
                let a = a.clone();
            }).unwrap();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0477]: the type `[closure@src/lib.rs:11:20: 13:14]` does not fulfill the required lifetime
  --> src/lib.rs:11:14
   |
11 |             .spawn(move || {
   |              ^^^^^
   |
   = note: type must satisfy the static lifetime
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b1208176ab5e36f84186ec1d85bfc337)

Actually I have an idea. If I take the lifetimes of `A` and remove the `a` member, it works. So it is possibly rejecting `a: Arc<Mutex<Self>>` inside of the spawned thread. When you spawn a thread, the closure must have a static lifetime:

```
pub fn spawn<F, T>(f: F) -> JoinHandle<T> 
    where F: FnOnce() -> T, 
          F: Send + 'static, 
          T: Send + 'static
```

so it looks like the fact that `a` is passed inside of the closure, makes the closure be not `'static`. But I don't see why, as `a: Arc<Mutex<Self>>` inside the thread lives as long as the closure. Could somebody explain in details what is happening? I'm confusing lifetime of things with lifetime of references, etc.

Comment: I _think_ there's nothing stopping your code from destroying the Arc and keeping the `&'a u8` reference in the thread, so the Arc doesn't guarantee that the thread won't reference something that has been freed.

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750829/how-can-i-pass-a-reference-to-a-stack-variable-to-a-thread what you're looking for, or do you actually want a persistent thread in the background referencing this `u8`? It isn't clear from your code why you want the reference so it is hard to suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `Arc<Mutex<Self>>` is moved into the closure and lives for as long as the closure is alive (dropping the closure drops the `Arc`), this is not sufficient here. As you have seen in the docs, the newly spawned thread could live forever (`'static`), and it requires the passed-in closure to be `'static`. But just wrapping something into an `Arc` does not make that thing `'static`:

If I give you some generic `A<'a>`, as part of `Arc<Mutex<Self>>`, with ANY lifetime `'a`, that lifetime `'a` could be shorter than `'static`. If you put this `A<'a>` into an `Arc` and pass it along, the destruction of the thing of lifetime `'a` (the `a`-member in this case) would make `A`, `Mutex<A>` and `Arc<Mutex<A>>` invalid.

In practical terms: Generic lifetimes can't be "solved" by wrapping them in atomic primitives, as they can't enforce a `'static` lifetime on their inhabitant.

What you are looking for is either

```
impl A<'static>{
    pub fn run(a: Arc<Mutex<Self>>) {
        
        let stack_thread = std::thread::Builder::new()
            .spawn(move || {
                let a = a.clone();
            }).unwrap();
    }
}
```

or you need to change the definition of `A` to be `'static` in any case, e.g. by holding a `Box<[u8]>` instead of a `&'a [u8]`.

Comment: Also note that the `let a = a.clone()` line is unneeded, as you already receive ownership for that argument. You don't need to clone, you just need to move: A `let a = a;` inside the closure will do that.

Comment: Does the `'static` mean that when the stack_thread stops, and no other copy of the `a: Arc<Mutex<Self>>` exists, the object still lives in memory? I always get confused at this

Comment: No, and this is often a source of confusion: `'static` does NOT mean that a value lives forever. It just means that the value _can be made_ to live forever. That is, `stack_thread` must be able _to make_ all things passed to it live forever if it so chooses, because it itself may run forever. It can make things live forever by simply not destroying those values. But if you pass some `A<'a>` for ANY `'a`, this may not be possible, because `'a` may be shorter than whatever `stack_thread` needs. `Arc` can't fix that.

Comment: This is why a `Vec<u8>`, a `Box<[u8]` or a `Arc<[u8]>` are `'static` and can be passed: Simply not destroying them is enough to make them live as long as we want. But a `&'a [u8]` has some - possibly shorter - lifetime `'a` at which point we _have_ to destroy it.