# add lifetime for a struct that invoke method in multi-threading environment

Tags: multithreading, rust, traits

This is my program:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, MutexGuard};
use std::thread;

trait Animal: Send + Sync { fn get_id(&self) -> i32; }

struct Cat {}

impl Animal for Cat {
    fn get_id(&self) -> i32 { return 0; }
}

struct Thread {
    id: i32,
    ptr: Arc<dyn Animal>,
}

impl Thread {
    pub fn multi_threading(&self) {
        let shared_array = Arc::new(Mutex::new([0; 5]));
        let mut handles = vec![];
        for _ in 0..5 {
            let array_ptr = Arc::clone(&shared_array);
            let handle = thread::spawn(move ||
                self.assign(&mut array_ptr.lock().unwrap())
            );
            handles.push(handle);
        }
        for handle in handles {
            handle.join().unwrap();
        }
    }

    pub fn assign(&self, array: &mut MutexGuard<[i32; 5]>) {
        array[self.id as usize] = self.id * self.id + self.ptr.get_id();
    }
}

unsafe impl Send for Thread {}

fn main() {
    let cat = Cat {};
    let ptr_cat = Arc::new(cat);
    let thread = Thread { id: 0, ptr: ptr_cat.clone() };
    thread.multi_threading();
}
```

struct `Thread` is defined with a pointer to a trait object, its member method `multi_threading` does nothing but assigning value to an array that can be accessed by several threads.

When I compile the program, the error says the `&self` from `pub fn multi_threading(&self)`

> has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement

Now where should I add this `'static` lifetime to satisfy the requirement, to get the program complied?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750829/how-can-i-pass-a-reference-to-a-stack-variable-to-a-thread)

Comment: You do not need `impl Send for Thread` at all, it automatically implements `Send` since you already require any `Animal` implementation is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your instance in an `Arc` itself. That way you can send it to your threads:

```rust
impl Thread {
    pub fn multi_threading(self: &Arc<Self>) {
        let shared_array = Arc::new(Mutex::new([0; 5]));
        let mut handles = vec![];
        for _ in 0..5 {
            let array_ptr = Arc::clone(&shared_array);
            let s = self.clone();
            let handle = thread::spawn(move ||
                s.assign(&mut array_ptr.lock().unwrap())
            );
            handles.push(handle);
        }
        for handle in handles {
            handle.join().unwrap();
        }
    }

    pub fn assign(&self, array: &mut MutexGuard<[i32; 5]>) {
        array[self.id as usize] = self.id * self.id + self.ptr.get_id();
    }
}
...

fn main() {
    let cat = Cat {};
    let ptr_cat = Arc::new(cat);
    let thread = Arc::new(Thread { id: 0, ptr: ptr_cat.clone() });
    thread.multi_threading();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1542bf45bc25a0c359432aa71759aa85)

Notice that you would not need `unsafe impl Send for Thread {}`, because with `Arc` it is safe to share it.