# Prevent value from moving after function call

Tags: rust

I have a rust program that I am creating that repeatedly runs a function in a thread, which causes a value moved error.

Here's some example code (pretty much the same as mine but simplified to get to the point and with a few names changed around)

```rust
use std::{thread}


struct Foo {
    bar: bool
}

impl Foo {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Foo { bar: false };
    }

    fn do_something2(self) {
        // do something

        // technically could be simplified here to self.bar = !some_condition, but someone will           
        // probably complain about it, not really relevant to the issue anyways
        if some_condition {
            self.bar = false;
        }
    }
}


fn do_something(mut foo: Foo) {
    foo.bar = true;

    thread::spawn(|| {
        while foo.bar {
           foo.do_something2();
        }
    });
}


fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo::new();
    do_something(&mut foo);
    // other code
}
```

I am not sure how I would stop the variable from being moved. In this example, it could technically be avoided by implementing the Copy trait, but my struct has a Vec as one of the values, so I cannot use Copy and need to find a different way.

Comment: `fn do_something(mut foo: Foo)` moves the `foo` into that function. You call it like you want it to be `fn do_something(foo: &mut Foo)` instead. But then you'll have problems with `thread::spawn`.

Comment: Same with `fn do_something2(self)` which should probably be `fn do_something2(&mut self)`

Comment: You can look at [how to use references to stack variables in a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750829/how-can-i-pass-a-reference-to-a-stack-variable-to-a-thread) to see how you coud prevent the move while still passing it to the thread.

Comment: @cafce25 I added the thread part to show that, like @PitaJ said, there would be conflicts with doing `fn do_something(foo: &mut Foo)`. The thread isn't causing the move, just re-referencing the variable. Sorry about my vague statement at the beginning of the question. I could try doing `fn do_something(&mut Foo)`, but then it will probably take longer to deal with the exceptions the thread causes (unless the thing you linked is an answer to that).

Comment: I decided to do the thing from @PitaJ's comment, but now I will have to do with the `\`foo\` has an anonymous lifetime \`'_\` but needs to fulfill a \`'static\` lifetime requirement`.

Edit: Should I create a new question for this?

Comment: Are we talking about moving `foo` in `main`? Or in other words is `//other code` using `foo`

Comment: The issue is that `thread::spawn` spawns a new thread but doesn't wait it to complete, so you can't access `foo` while the thread could potentially still be using it. You need some way to enforce exclusive access to `foo`, potentially a mutex. Why are you spawning threads? Could you provide a bigger picture of what you're trying to do? I'm curious why you chose this approach.

Comment: Just a note: you can get around that limitation of `thread::spawn` by using `thread::scope` instead.

Comment: @Coder-256 I am going to change something using the main thread, using multithreading so the function can be run simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll want `do_something` to take a reference rather than an owned value. You can do that like so:

```rust
fn do_something(foo: &mut Foo) { ... }
```

The method `Foo::doo_something2` should also be changed to take a mutable reference:

```rust
fn do_something2(&mut self) { ... }
```

Once you do that you'll encounter a new error. `thread::spawn` has no way to prove that the reference outlives the thread that is being created. Lucky for you there is a new feature in the standard library called "scoped threads" that allows you to prove to the compiler that `foo` won't be dropped before the child thread terminates.

You can use scoped threads like so:

```rust
fn do_something(foo: &mut Foo) {
    foo.bar = true;

    thread::scope(|scope| {
        scope.spawn(|| {
            while foo.bar {
                foo.do_something2();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Now I get an error with the compiler complaining about it being an unsafe feature, probably a quick fix but I'm new to rust so not sure what to do.

Comment: Followup to my other message: I am stupid and using outdated rust, updated and it works now