# How to pass &[&str] into thread?

Tags: rust, concurrency

I have `&[&str]` and need to calculate frequencies of characters by using `worker_count` threads.

This example is done for education purposes and have many alternative solutions. Some of them I found limiting for improving my understanding of Rust:

1. Solution using channels
2. Solution using `thread::scope` - requirement that threads will be forced joined, if had not done before. This should be done before exiting scope.
3. Solution using `rayon` or `crossbeam` libs, like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750829/how-can-i-pass-a-reference-to-a-stack-variable-to-a-thread)

**My first iteration**

```rust
use std::{collections::HashMap, sync::{Mutex, Arc}, thread};

pub fn frequency(input: &[&str], worker_count: usize) -> HashMap<char, usize> {
    let input_len = input.len();
    let acc = Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::<char, usize>::new()));
    let counter: Arc<Mutex<usize>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(input_len));
    let mut handles: Vec<thread::JoinHandle<()>> = vec![];
    let input_vec = input.to_vec();
    let shared_strings =  Arc::new(input_vec);
    for _ in 0..worker_count {
        let counter = Arc::clone(&counter);
        let acc: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<char, usize>>> = Arc::clone(&acc);
        let shared_strings = Arc::clone(&shared_strings);
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            let target_idx: usize;
            {
                let mut i = counter.lock().unwrap();
                if *i == 0 {
                    return;
                }
                *i -= 1;
                target_idx = *i;
            }
            let d = HashMap::<char, usize>::new();
            {
                let input_string = shared_strings[target_idx];
                // populate d based on input string
                // merge d and acc hashmaps together
            }
            
        });
        handles.push(handle);
    }
    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
    *acc.lock().unwrap()
}
```

As of now, with code above I cannot pass `input: &[&str]` into every thread cos Rust drops unclear message to me: `input escapes the function body here` (Why `input` is still relevant if I made a `input_vec: Vec<&str>` that can outlive it?

```
borrowed data escapes outside of function
`input` escapes the function body here

borrowed data escapes outside of function
argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`

borrowed data escapes outside of function
argument requires that `'2` must outlive `'static`
```

**EDIT 1**

My first solution: pass `&[&str]` by converting it to owned `Vec<String>`

```rust
pub fn frequency(input: &[&str], worker_count: usize) -> HashMap<char, usize> {
    let input_len = input.len();
    let acc = Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::<char, usize>::new()));
    let counter: Arc<Mutex<usize>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(input_len));
    let mut handles: Vec<thread::JoinHandle<()>> = vec![];
    let vec_input: Vec<String> = input.iter().map(|s| s.to_string()).collect();
    let shared_strings =  Arc::new(vec_input);
    for _ in 0..worker_count {
        let counter = Arc::clone(&counter);
        let acc: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<char, usize>>> = Arc::clone(&acc);
        let shared_strings = Arc::clone(&shared_strings);
   
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            loop {
                let target_idx: usize;
                {
                    let mut i = counter.lock().unwrap();
                    if *i == 0 {
                        return;
                    }
                    *i -= 1;
                    target_idx = *i;
                }

                let input_string = shared_strings.get(target_idx).unwrap();
                
                // populate d based on input string
                let mut d = HashMap::<char, usize>::new();
                for c in input_string.chars() {
                    if !c.is_alphabetic() {
                        continue;
                    }
                    let key = c.to_ascii_lowercase();
                    let fq: &mut usize = d.entry(key).or_insert(0);
                    *fq += 1;
                }

                // merge d and acc hashmaps together
                let mut acc = acc.lock().unwrap();
                for (c, fq) in &d {
                    let fq_acc: &mut usize = acc.entry(*c).or_insert(0);
                    *fq_acc += fq;
                }
            }
        });
        handles.push(handle);
    }
    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

    let result = acc.lock().unwrap().clone();
    result
}
```

This solution is raising a question if I can partially lock `acc:  HashMap<char, usize>` for specific keys I am currently editing to improve performance.

Comment: `input` is still relevant because the `&str` in `input_vec` still refer to the original `input`. You can fix the issue using [scoped threads](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html) (at which point you no longer need `input_vec` or the `Arc`s since you can pass the references directly to the threads).